# Conditional Formula in Excel - date based

Tags: date, colors, conditional-formatting

I've been looking around for this for a couple days but haven't found exactly what I need so here we go:

Cell C2 is a date, cell G2 is a dollar amount.
If/When C2 is one-year-old I need G2 to turn red.

Ex.)

C2 = 6/1/2018, G2 = $250 in red

or

C3 = 2/1/2021, G3 = $250 in black (but will turn red on 2/2/2022)

thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Create Conditional Formatting for G2 (New Rule -> Use a formula to determine which cells to format) and use this formula:

=DATEDIF(C2,TODAY(),"Y")>0

Rest of the formatting like color border etc. set as you like.

**Edit:**
I realised that this will put G2 in red on the same day next year. For example:

C3 = 2/1/2021, G3 = $250 in black (but will turn red on **2/1/2022**)

If you need it next day just modify formula to this:

=DATEDIF(C2,TODAY()-1,"Y")>0